# Proof that set is dense

Tags: real-analysis

If a set $E$ is dense, how do I show that $R$ \ $E$ is dense? I tried working with the definition of dense (that there every interval contains a point of the set), but I was unable to make much progress.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $E$ countable? Then it's true. @Tsemo's counterexample shows you need something for the statement to hold.

Comment: I edited the question - does it make more sense now?

Comment: Probably you shouldn't edit a question so freely if you are doing so in response to someone's answer - now Tsemo's answer "it's not true" is no longer relevant...

Comment: OK, I edited it back

Comment: sorry - I hadn't meant that you shouldn't change your question at all. only that in this case you append to it, perhaps, for example., "Edit - in response to,.."  anyway - maybe this is the kind of thing you were looking for, after the fact:   if $X$ is separable (aka, contains a countable - where countable could be finite - dense set), then any subset of $X$ is separable... so $R \setminus E$ contains a countable dense set.

Answer (score 3):

It is not true, because if  $R$ is the real line, it is dense and $R-R$ is empty and is not dense.

Comment: And if you want an example of a proper dense subset, $R\setminus\{0\}$ will do.